# Creating a JavaScript timer by clicking OK prompts

Tags: javascript

I need to create a timer and want to measure the time from Clicking OK to start till the user clicks OK stop. I just want to display the time difference between clicking the OK's. Does anyone know how to do this as simply as possible? Although it may seem easy for most of you i'm really sturggling to work it out, any help is appreciated

```
var canvas;
canvas = openGraphics();

alert( "Press \"OK\" to start the timer." );

alert( "Press \"OK\" to stop the timer." );


canvas.paint();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/g74ssnku/1/

```
alert("ok start")
var starttime = Date.now();
alert("ok stop")
var stoptime = Date.now();
var seconds_between = (stoptime - starttime)/1000 ;
alert(seconds_between + " seconds");
```

Just record the time between the two confirmations and you should be fine.

Comment: this was very useful thanks, have any idea how i would add an IF statement for certain times for example something like 
if (time > 100) = green

Comment: You're welcome :) Sure. You can check the 'seconds_between' variable , like 
'if(seconds_between > 10) { do_something() }'. If you need to check for a certain timeinterval and are struck just let me know what exactly you want to do or open another question :)

Comment: specifically i need to "Add appropriate lines of code so that event values below 150mS are displayed in green, values of 151-350mS in orange and over 350mS in red." https://jsfiddle.net/will_brammer/s7eyof1o/

Answer (score 1):

Have an OK button, perhaps:

```
<input type="button" id="the-button" value="OK">
```

In a script tag somewhere after that HTML (at the end of the document is good), have a `timer` variable which is initially `0`:

```
var timer = 0;
```

...and add an event handler for the button:

```
document.getElementById("the-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
    // ...we'll add more here in a moment...
}, false);
```

When the user clicks the button, if `timer` is `0`, record the starting time; if not, report the difference and reset it to `0`:

```
document.getElementById("the-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var elapsed;
    if (timer === 0) {
        timer = Date.now();
    } else {
        elapsed = Date.now() - timer; // In milliseconds
        alert("Elapsed time: " + elapsed); // Or whatever you want to do with it
        timer = 0;
    }
}, false);
```

Live Example:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  var timer = 0;
  document.getElementById("the-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var elapsed;
    if (timer === 0) {
      timer = Date.now();
    } else {
      elapsed = Date.now() - timer; // In milliseconds
      alert("Elapsed time: " + elapsed);
      timer = 0;
    }
  }, false);
})();
```

```html
<input type="button" id="the-button" value="OK">
```

---

Note: That uses `addEventListener`, which is supported by all modern browsers (including IE9). To support old IE (such as IE8), you'll have to handle the fact that it uses `attachEvent` instead of `addEventListener`. Similarly, `Date.now` is not in IE8, but can be polyfilled for old browsers:

```
if (!Date.now) {
    Date.now = function() {
        return +new Date();
    };
}
```

Comment: Good answer. But I think OP wanted to measure the time between two alerts. (But I might be wrong, question is not that clear in my opinion)

Comment: @TimHallyburton: Hmmm, you may be right. If so, you've got it covered. :-)